# How to encrypt data from server side and pass it to client side(javascript) and decrypt and use it

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net-mvc, json, encryption

I have a json string generated at server side in mvc and i access that json string in client side by simply rendering it to the html (plain).

THis json string contains some important values which should not be shared to everyone.
It will be visible if someone views the source page.

How can i hide my json string?

I thought of encrypt and decrypt, but decrypting value on client side which is encrypted on 
server side. I find it bit strange.

Comment: Who do you want to protect against? If you don't want external party to read the information transmitted over the Internet you should use an TLS/HTTPS connection. If you don't want a valid user to access the json data you are mostly out of luck. You can make it difficult for him/her by obscuring the data a bit but in the end if your client side application can read, so can the user.

Comment: no luck with encryption even?

Comment: Encryption is about protecting data against someone how does not have the encryption key. But if your javascript code has access to the key in some way then the user can also extract it, for example by viewing the javascript source or using a debugger to look up the values of the variables used.

Comment: ohhh yes.. didn't thought of that.. "Out Of luck"

Have to go with Https then..

Thanks

Comment: @Perseids I think you should post that as an answer.

Comment: If you want to user to eventually see the information, couldn't you use some form of asynchronous encryption? Or does the user not need to seem the info?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Who do you want to protect against? If you don't want external parties to read the information transmitted over the Internet you should use a TLS/HTTPS connection. If you don't want a valid user to access the json data you are mostly out of luck. You can make it difficult for him/her by obscuring the data a bit but in the end if your client side application can read, so can the user.

Encryption can help you with this obfuscation but ultimately it is about protecting data against someone who does not have the encryption key. If your javascript code has access to the key in some way then the user can also extract it, for example by viewing the javascript source or using a debugger to look up the values of the variables used.

Answer (score 0):

If you are on .net platform then you can use the session state to store that value. Value store in session are secure because server store them in encrypted form. However quick and fast way is to store in viewstate but that can be trapped easily (not secure).

Comment: Note that you are not actually transferring any (usable) data to the client side then, which seems to be what rusty wants to do, displaying it in the browser.